# Mapapi v2 in android causing error in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I am having little problem in map implementation in `fragment`.
Below is my code.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.tfick.android.R;

public class PoiFragment extends Fragment{

private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(23.03,72.62);

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.poi_fragment, container,false);


    MapFragment  mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container1, mMapFragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();

     if(mGoogleMap ==null){

            /*initializing map */

            mGoogleMap=mMapFragment.getMap();

            /*cretaing custom camera position*/

            CameraPosition mCameraPosition=new CameraPosition.Builder().target(SYDNEY).bearing(0).tilt(30).build();

            /*setting custom camera position*/

            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));

            /*adding custom marker on the map.*/
             mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().draggable(true).position(new LatLng(22.03, 72.56)).title("hello world").snippet("Ahmedabad").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.wifi)));

            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().draggable(true).position(new LatLng(23.03, 78.10)).title("hello world").snippet("Baroda").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.wifi)));

        }

        if(mGoogleMap !=null){


            /* map is already initialized then setting map type */
            /*
             * normal 
             * satellite
             * hybrid
             * terrain
             * none
             */
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        }

    return v;
}
}
```

```
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.tfick.android/com.tfick.android.PointOfIntrest}: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.at.a(Unknown Source)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.J(Unknown Source)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(Unknown Source)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at com.tfick.fragment.PoiFragment.onCreateView(PoiFragment.java:51)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5215)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
03-01 12:15:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(9299):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to me i find the solution 
if any once have same problem use following code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.tfick.android.R;

public class PoiFragment extends MapFragment {
    /*object of google map*/
    public GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    /* summy location*/
    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(23.03, 72.62);


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (getMap() != null) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Map ready for use!");

            mGoogleMap = getMap();

            /* cretaing custom camera position */

            CameraPosition mCameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(SYDNEY).bearing(0).tilt(30).build();
            Log.i("gmap", mGoogleMap.toString());

            /* setting custom camera position */

            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));

            /* adding custom marker on the map. */
            mGoogleMap
                    .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .draggable(true)
                            .position(new LatLng(22.03, 72.56))
                            .title("hello world")
                            .snippet("Ahmedabad")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.wifi)));

            mGoogleMap
                    .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .draggable(true)
                            .position(new LatLng(23.03, 78.10))
                            .title("hello world")
                            .snippet("Baroda")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.wifi)));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer @Bug, you've pasted your entire activity here. Try to remove irrelevant parts, that way others can use it too and upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the CameraUpdateFactory.
 As per the documentation - 
Call **initialize(Context)**. As long as a **GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException** isn't thrown, this class will be correctly initialized.

Link-

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer.html#initialize(android.content.Context)

How to initialize -

```
try {
     MapsInitializer.initialize(this /*the context*/);
 } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Reference - [mapview and cameraupdate in api v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905230/mapview-and-cameraupdate-in-api-v2)

Comment: it is showing error in
 CameraPosition mCameraPosition=new CameraPosition.Builder().target(SYDNEY).bearing(0).tilt(30).build();

Comment: Did you try calling initialize?

Comment: when i comment that if conditions it shows no error and map load like a charm but when i use that if conditions it shows error.
and i am not using mapview i am using mapFragment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getMap()` returns `null` and hence `CameraUpdateFactory` throws the exceptions as it needs an initialised `GoogleMap`.

I had a similar problem when using a `MapFragment` inside a `Fragment`. I solved it by moving  the map initialisation to `OnResume`.

Answer (score 0):

The Google map implementation relies heavily on several life-cycle methods (onCreate, onCreateView, onDestroy, onResume and onPause). You should relay those calls to the MapFragment if you encapsulate it within you own fragment. The map should already be initialized after you call mapView.getMap() and get a GoogleMap in return.

If you get null from getMap() several things might have happened:

- You didn't call onCreate and/or onCreateView on the MapFragment (call getMap() after those methods)
- You are lacking the OpenGL ES 2 feature entry in your manifest
- You are lacking the required permissions for maps
- Google Play SDK Services are not installed on the device or they are too old

I read about the initialize(this) solution quite often here on StackOverflow but it is actually not needed in most of the cases.

**EDIT:**
I just saw that you are adding the Mapfragment through a transaction. Have you considered using just a MapView instead within your PoiFragment? I believe that by using the MapFragment and adding it through a transaction you get a timing issue. The transaction is propably not finished while you are still in your PoiFragment.onCreateView method (hence Maps is not initialized, yet). You could try using onResume but you would have to make sure, that you init your map code only once as onResume will be called more often.

My suggestions in terms of architecture:

- Use MapFragment directly within your activity if that is feasible
- Extend the Mapfragment if you have enough code to put in there

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly same problem.This error happens when `getMap()` returns `null`.

I did the following:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();

/* if googleMap == null then there may be following problem :
 * 1. google play service version are not matching on both device and installed apk.Will show update message on map.
 * 2. No google play service installed. Will show a install message on map.
 */
if (googleMap != null) {
    LatLng iniLoc = new LatLng(44.97651081283853, -93.2245754142059);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(iniLoc));
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
    currentMarkerOption = new MarkerOptions();
    currentMarkerOption.position(iniLoc);
    currentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(currentMarkerOption);
    currentMarker.setIcon((BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
    currentMarker.setTitle("Current Position");
    currentMarker.showInfoWindow();
    currentMarker.setVisible(false);
    initDestinationMarker();
}
```