# MapFragment - CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

Tags: android, google-maps

I get the following error in my app reported by Google Play:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
at com.google.android.gms.internal.x.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.aE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(Unknown Source)
at com.foo.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:144)
```

I've already read posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905230/mapview-and-cameraupdate-in-api-v2). My code in `DetailActivity` (extends FragmentActivity) follows:

```
try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    Log.e("map", " " + e.getMessage());
}

SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(settings.getFloat("lat", -28.709861f), settings.getFloat("lon", 26.015625f)))
    .zoom(settings.contains("lat") ? 11 : 6)
    .build();
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition); //line 144
```

I'm not sure how it's still uninitialised. At this point in my code, I haven't created the MapFragment yet. I don't see this would need to be after creating the MapFragment though, since I'm not calling anything from the MapFragment.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: `I haven't created the MapFragment yet.`
You haven't added `MapFragment` to the layout at all?

Comment: Not until about 10 lines later. I first initialize the map-related stuff, then set it up using all the relevant stuff.

Comment: Code looks ok and the javadoc for MapInitializer specifically states that it will initialize the CameraUpdateFactory. Are you sure there isn't a GooglePlayServiceNotAvailableException being thrown and your not missing it in the logs?

Comment: Potentially, but I don't have logs because the exception came via the Play Store. I can try recreate the error locally I guess. If the problem is GooglePlayServiceNotAvailableException, then what? Give the user a message and abort showing the map? I'm not sure how one can recover from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the next update replace:

```
Log.e("map", " " + e.getMessage());
```

with:

```
throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

At least you will get the real reason and not the symptom NPE.

Anyway if Google Play Services are not installed on user's device this code should never try to execute.

There are things like [`GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29) and other functions which will help you.

Comment: The problem with just throwing exceptions is that we get ungraceful exits. Failing gracefully is nice for the customer, but failing with detail is nicer for us developers.

Comment: You could also just change this to Log.e("map", " " + e.getMessage(), e); which will print out the stack trace (including the "causedBy" reason, which is what you're after) as part of the log message.

Comment: @Elroid This won't help as the exception on user's device happened on line 144. With ACRA included developer could have access to the error log, but without it's just like there was no code there.